# How to group rows in pandas with sum in the certain column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a DataFrame like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | unique_ident_1 | 10 | ONE |
| 1 | KLM | unique_ident_2 | 2 | TEN |
| 2 | KLM | unique_ident_2 | 7 | TEN |
| 3 | XYZ | unique_ident_3 | 2 | TWO |
| 3 | ABC | unique_ident_1 | 8 | ONE |
| 3 | XYZ | unique_ident_3 | -5 | TWO |

where  column "B" contains a unique text identifier, columns "A" and "D" contain some constant texts dependent from unique id, and column C has a quantity. I want to group rows by unique identifiers (col "B") with quantity column summed up by ident:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | unique_ident_1 | 18 | ONE |
| 1 | KLM | unique_ident_2 | 9 | TEN |
| 2 | XYZ | unique_ident_3 | -3 | TWO |

How can I get this result with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a dictionary and then group incase you have many columns:

```
agg_d = {col:'sum' if col=='C' else'first' for col in df.columns}
out = df.groupby('B').agg(agg_d).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(out)

     A               B   C    D
0  ABC  unique_ident_1  18  ONE
1  KLM  unique_ident_2   9  TEN
2  XYZ  unique_ident_3  -3  TWO
```

Comment: very smart, nice one!

Answer (score 3):

use named tuples with a groupby.

```
df1 = df.groupby('B',as_index=False).agg(
    A=('A','first'),
    C=('C','sum'),
    D=('D','first')
)[df.columns]


     A               B   C    D
0  ABC  unique_ident_1  18  ONE
1  KLM  unique_ident_2   9  TEN
2  XYZ  unique_ident_3  -3  TWO
```